# Change vertical space after group header for nomecl?

Tags: spacing, nomenclature, nomencl

With the `nomencl` package I have items categorized into several groups (by suitably defining `\nomgroup`).

How can one change the vertical space *after* each group heading, i.e., between the group heading and the first item of that group? (I already know how to change the vertical space before the group heading, as shown below with `\nomgroupstartsep`).

Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}    
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Index of Notation}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\unskip, #1}

\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

\newlength{\nomgroupstartsep}
\setlength{\nomgroupstartsep}{16pt}

\newcommand{\nomenclheader}[1]{\item[\hspace*{-\itemindent}\bfseries#1]}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
 \itemsep\nomgroupstartsep%
  \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
   {C}{\nomenclheader{Constants}}% 
   {S}{\nomenclheader{Sets}}%
  }%
  \itemsep\nomitemsep% restore spacing
}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

The number $\pi$ is the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter;
$e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.%
\nomenclature[c2]{$\pi$}{ratio of circle's circumference to diameter}
\nomenclature[c1]{$e$}{base of natural logarithm}

Write $x \in A$ to mean that $x$ is an element of the set $A$.%
\nomenclature[s3]{$x \in A$}{$x$ is an element of $A$}
For sets $A$ and $B$, the notation $A \subset B$ means that $A$ is a subset of $B$.%
\nomenclature[s4]{$A \subset B$}{$A$ is a subset of $B$}    
Use lower-case letters $x$, $y$, $z$, etc., for elements of sets, and upper-case letters $A$, $B$, $C$, etc., for sets.%
\nomenclature[s1]{$x$, $y$, $z$, etc.}{elements of sets}
\nomenclature[s2]{$A$, $B$, $C$, etc.}{sets}

\printnomenclature[2.5cm]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that looks all pretty hackish to me ... so why not add one more hack: `\newcommand{\nomenclheader}[1]{\item[\hspace*{-\itemindent}\bfseries#1]{\ } \vspace{\baselineskip}\par}` - replace `\baselineskip` by whatever amount of vertical space you fancy.

Comment: Aha: the trick was adding the `{\ }` before the `\vspace`! I don't see why the `\par` is needed though: I'm not seeing any difference with it from without it. A hackish situation does seem to call for more hacks. If you'll post your comment as an answer and nobody has a cleaner way to do the whole spacing thing, I certainly accept the answer.

Comment: I didn't investigate whether the `\par` was needed or not - I have run into cases where `\vspace` showed up in the wrong places without it, so it's become a habit of mine to follow `\vspace` with `\par` in all my macro definitions. Too lazy to post an answer, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: I don't see why my question was outside the scope of TeX, LaTeX: it concerned a LaTeX package.